# Comparar texto crystal report

Tags: c#

Boa tarde.
Gostaria de saber como montar uma formula no crystal report para que veja, se a no texto a palavra "QTDA", se existir ele sinalize a celula toda com a cor vermelha, caso não não faça nada...

Comment: Estou sem o CR aqui mas tem uma function que faz isto ,POS ou INSTR creio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:Clique com botão direito na coluna e vá em "Format Object"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2:Aba Moldura
3:Seção cor, onde tem a opção Plano de Fundo, clique no botão ao lado Fórmula

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4:Utilize a seguinte formula abaixo:

```
If instr({@Campo}, "QTDA") <> 0
   Then crRed
```